# What is the omitted word in this sentence? (do or make?)

Tags: ellipsis

There is a sentence below,

1. I don't want to make anyone do anything that I don't want to.

What is the omitted word at the end of the sentence above? 'do' or 'make'?
And Is there any regulation to omit words? or should we decide what word is omitted in the sentence depending only on the context?
please give me the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you get this example? Even if it be correct grammatically, it sounds unfamiliar to the ear. It would sound more natural to change it to one of the following two.

> I don't want to make anyone do anything (that) I don't do (myself).

> I don't want to make anyone do anything (that) they don't want to (do).

In either the examples, as you see, *do* is the right answer, not *make*. You are talking about *not doing something*, not about *not making something*. That's why you don't want to force others to *do* what you don't *do* yourself.